I want to achieve the effect of chain adsorption, but the end cannot stick tightly
I want to achieve a situation where, when I drag the end of the chain to the object on the right, the end sticks to the object (i.e., both sides are parallel). However, I tried adding constraints to two points, and it had no effect, and even a single point constraint didn't work.
Now my idea is to create a groove where the end of the chain can be embedded or removed.
How can this be achieved? (Providing a specific method to achieve the effect of the two sides sticking together would also be helpful.)
my codepan demo: https://codepen.io/your-work


window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  const {
    Engine,
    Render,
    World,
    Bodies,
    Composite,
    Runner,
    Mouse,
    MouseConstraint,
    Constraint,//约束(类似弹簧等等)
    Events,Body,Composites
  } = Matter;

  var engine = Engine.create();
  var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine
  });

  // 创建插座socket600, 200, 40, 20
  const mainRectangle = Bodies.rectangle(600, 200, 40, 20, {
    isStatic: true,
    render: { fillStyle: "#ff0000" }
  });
  //580, 200, 20, 15
  const notch = Bodies.rectangle(580, 200, 20, 15,{isStatic: true,});
  //Body.setPosition(notch, { x: 580, y: 225 });
  //Body.setPosition(notch, { x: 180, y: 225 });
  const socket = Body.create({
    parts: [mainRectangle, notch],
    isStatic: true
  });
  World.add(engine.world, socket);
  
  // 创建链
  var group = Body.nextGroup(true);
  //12会扭动,10会像鱼一样扭动
  var ropeA = Composites.stack(100, 50, 10, 1, 5, 5, function (x, y) {
    //创建刚体(链节)
    return Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 50, 10, {
      collisionFilter: { group: group },
      damping:1,
      frictionAir: 0.001 //空气阻力
    });
  });
  //将复合主体的所有主体(一系列刚体)链接起来;
  Composites.chain(ropeA, 0.5, 0, -0.5, 0, {
    stiffness: 0.8,//链接硬度，越大越坚固不易弯曲
    length: 2,//每个连接之间的间距
    render: { type: "line" } //渲染器设置，这里设置显示出连接的线条
  });
  //*向一个复合体（Composite）中添加新的元素。
  //复合体(链子)上再添加单个或多个主体、约束或复合体[挂点]
  Composite.add(
    ropeA,//复合体
    Constraint.create({ //用于创建一个约束（类似一个虚拟的弹簧或杆），连接两个物体或一个物体的两个点。
      bodyB: ropeA.bodies[0],
      pointB: { x: -25, y: 0 },
      pointA: { x: ropeA.bodies[0].position.x, y: ropeA.bodies[0].position.y },
      damping:1,//越大，弹力越弱
      stiffness: 0.8//弹性程度，数值越高越不容易拉伸
    })
  );
  // 添加链和地面
  Composite.add(engine.world, [
    //socket,
    ropeA,
    Bodies.rectangle(400, 600, 1200, 50.5, { isStatic: true }),
    //socket
  ]);

  // 添加鼠标控制
  var mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas);
  var mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
    mouse: mouse,
    constraint: {
      stiffness: 0.2,
      render: {
        visible: false
      }
    }
  });
  Composite.add(engine.world, mouseConstraint);

  // 生成器和渲染器
  var runner = Runner.create();
  Runner.run(runner, engine);
  Render.run(render);

  // 变量来跟踪链子的末端是否连接到插座
  let isPluggedIn = false;
  let endConstraint_top = null,
      endConstraint_bottom = null;
  // 事件监听器: 在每次刷新时检测链子的末端是否接触到插座
  Events.on(engine, "beforeUpdate", function () {
    const endBody = ropeA.bodies[ropeA.bodies.length - 1];
    //计算两个向量的长度
    const distance = Matter.Vector.magnitude(
      Matter.Vector.sub(socket.position, endBody.position)
    );

    if (distance < 46 && !isPluggedIn) {
      // 吸附效果：创建约束将链子的末端固定到插座
      endConstraint_top = Constraint.create({ //约束
        bodyA: endBody,
        pointA: { x: 25, y: 2.5 },
        bodyB: socket,
        pointB: { x: -10, y: 2.5 },
        stiffness: 0.6,//0.9
        length: 0//0
      });
      endConstraint_bottom = Constraint.create({ //约束
        bodyA: endBody,
        pointA: { x: 25, y: -2.5 },
        bodyB: socket,
        pointB: { x: -10, y: 2.5 },
        stiffness: 0.6,//0.9
        length: 0//0
      });
      Composite.add(engine.world, [endConstraint_top,endConstraint_bottom]);//将约束添加入去，世界
      isPluggedIn = true;
    } else if (isPluggedIn && distance > 46) {
      // 拔出效果：移除约束
      Composite.remove(engine.world, [endConstraint_top,endConstraint_bottom]);
      endConstraint = null;
      isPluggedIn = false;
    }
  });

  // 事件监听器: 当鼠标拖动时，检测是否需要解除插座连接
  // Events.on(mouseConstraint, "enddrag", function (event) {
  //   if (event.body === ropeA.bodies[ropeA.bodies.length - 1] && isPluggedIn) {
  //     const endBody = ropeA.bodies[ropeA.bodies.length - 1];
  //     const distance = Matter.Vector.magnitude(
  //       Matter.Vector.sub(socket.position, endBody.position)
  //     );
  //     if (distance > 30) {
  //       // 拔出效果：移除约束
  //       Composite.remove(engine.world, endConstraint);
  //       endConstraint = null;
  //       isPluggedIn = false;
  //     }
  //   }
  // });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>文档标题</title>
  <script src="https://icdn.fongdan.com/js/matter.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
</body>
</html>



